# k-means segmentation of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I came across the following code, which segments an image using `num` no. of clusters, via the k-means clustering algorithm. However, I could not understand the meaning of the second statement in the first `for` loop. Please help me understand what the statement is doing and also what `~=` means(here).

Also, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
??? Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.

Error in ==> kmeansseg at 42
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
```

It seem that I get this error for every value other than `num=3`. So, does it mean that I cannot cluster an rgb image into more than 3 colors? The input image has 6 colors that I can tell apart. Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Function call:

```
>> f=imread('peppers.png'); 

>> kmeansseg(f,6)
```

Here is the code:

```
function kmeansseg(im,num)


figure(1),imshow(im), title('original image');

cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_im = applycform(im,cform);

ab = double(lab_im(:,:,2:3));

nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

nColors = num;

[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
    'Replicates',3);

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
figure(2),imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

segmented_images = cell(1,nColors);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 nColors]);

for k = 1:nColors
    color = im;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;      %meaning?
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end


figure(3),imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');

figure(4),imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');

figure(5),imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');



end
end
```

Comment: How you call this function? What input arguments are you using? Please add the function call.

Comment: @kkuilla, function call:
`>> f=imread('peppers.png');`

`>> kmeansseg(f,6)`

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is setting to zero any elements of the image that don't correspond to that particular label. That's how you get a series of segmented images. It gets the segregation labels from the `rgb_label` variable.

What ~= means there is "for every pixel of the segmentation image is NOT equal to the current segmentation number, set the image pixel to zero, leaving the other image pixels unchanged"

In regards to your edit - it looks like the color and rgb_label matrices do not have the same dimensions.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the dimensions of the matrices, but I suspect that's the problem

Comment: I am using the standard `peppers.png` image with dimensions `<384x512x3 uint8>`.

Comment: Could you just get the code to output the dimensions of color and rgb_label right after this line: `color = im;`

Comment: `rgb_label` size: `384x512x6` and `color` size `384x512x3`. Is it because I am trying to segment the image into 6 clusters? My input is `>>kmeansseg(f,6)` (`f` is the input image).

Comment: I'm not able to verify in depth, but it feels like the function is set up to expect a monochrome image, as opposed to RGB. You should be able to select as many clusters as you'd like, it shouldn't be linked to the number of colour channels in your image

Comment: The function was set up to take in rgb images as input. I took the code from [the mathworks site](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html).

Comment: Ahhh, in that case, num shouldn't be passed to the function, because it can either be derived from the input image, or will always be 3 if it's always used on RGB images

Comment: So, does it mean that I cannot cluster an rgb image into more than 3 colors? The input image has 6 colors that I can tell apart. Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You could try converting the image to HSV, and only using the hue layer as a monochrome image. I would suggest looking at this first: [Adaptive kmeans Clustering for Color and Gray Image](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45057-adaptive-kmeans-clustering-for-color-and-gray-image)